# Where are flex libraries located?

Tags: dpkg, libraries, find

I find myself with a very weird problem in my hands. I wanted to install both flex (the fast lexical analyzer) and bison, and that's why I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install bison flex
```

The installation goes on without errors and, as a matter of fact, if I type

```
dpkg -L flex
```

I end up with a list of entries which includes

```
/usr/lib
```

And, in that path, I expect to find the flex libraries (which as far as I know are libfl.a or libfl.so, depending if the installation was shared or static), but, lo and behold, there's no libfl library under /usr/lib, and using

```
find -L 'libfl.a' (or 'libfl.so')
```

returns only

```
No such file or directory
```

I'm completely puzzled...where should flex libraries be located?

Thanks

Comment: `locate libfl.a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files are in the `libfl-dev` package, which is a dependency of `flex`. The package is Multi-Arch enabled, so the files are under the `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` or `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` directory, depending on whether you are on 32 or 64 bit. Or possibly under `/usr/lib/armhf-linux-gnu/` if you are on ARM.